# Save json to database using entity framework

Tags: json, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am newbie to entity framework and struggling a bit to to save a simple JSON response to database.
I have a JSON string and used json2csharp.com to generate entity classes as below. As far as I see I need  to have tables for ABC,AAA,BBB,CCC in the database.

I thought with Entity framework I can simple add each ABC list and then just do savechanges but apparently its not that simple :-(

```
any pointers to fix the code ?

db.ABC.Add(listitem);
db.SaveChanges();


 public class ABC
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public AAA aaa { get; set; }
        public List<BBB> bbb { get; set; }
    }

 public class AAA
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }    
        public string bla { get; set; }    
    }  

    public class BBB
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }
        public List<CCC> images { get; set; }
        public object errorDetails { get; set; }
    }   

      public class CCC
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }
        public string bla { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject : DbContext
    {
        public List<ABC> abc { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public object errorDetails { get; set; }
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
RootObject robj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
 using (var db = new RootObject())
                {
                        foreach (ABC listitem in robj.ABC)                        
                        {                            
                           db.abc.Add(listitem);
                        }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I try the below code

using (var db = new RootObject())
                {                                                             
                    for (int i = 0; i < robj.abc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        db.abc.Add((ABC)robj.abc[i]);                            
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

Answer (score 0):

You have to totally change your **RootObject** class. It is not created correctly for EF to work and to be mapped with your DB. Better read http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx this official tutorial and try to reproduce it by yourself.

You will gain the understanding of EF and make the correct one **RootObject** :)

**Updated**

Edited sample for your code.

```
public class ABC
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public virtual AAA aaa { get; set; }

    //Collection navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<BBB> bbbs { get; set; }
}

public class AAA
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string bla { get; set; }
    public string bla2 { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public virtual ABC abc { get; set; }
}

public class BBB
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string bla { get; set; }
    public string bla4 { get; set; }
    public string bla3 { get; set; }
    public object errorDetails { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public virtual ABC abc { get; set; }

    //Collection navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<CCC> cccs { get; set; }
}

public class CCC
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string bla { get; set; }
    public string bla2 { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public virtual BBB bbb { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ABC> abc { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AAA> aaa { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BBB> bbb { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CCC> ccc { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }
    public object errorDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link to useful reading. Can you also point may be 1 correction to RootObject class ?

Comment: Ur welcome. Yeap: **public List<ABC> abc { get; set; }** must be **public DbSet<ABC> abc { get; set; }** . And you have to add all the other models you want them to be as tables as **DbSet<yourModel> yourModels {get; set;}** and connection between them and so on.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am confused about if it should be array or List - List<ABC> or ABC[] ?

Comment: Must be **DbSet** :) **DbSet** is a kind of a **List** for EF. Look updated answer.

Comment: I think I made some progress here and all the classes got created in the database through EF.
But now  when I do db.savechanges I keep getting
"{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
and iner exception is 
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id

I am explicitly setting id for all entities so this is breaking my head :-(

Comment: now I can save the json response to database so little progress :-) - thanks to your tips n  hints. 
But new challenges - id field in each table by default is primary key but in json response it could be null. I already have the NullValueHandling set to ignore but apprently thats is not helping and causing database save to fail.
any ideas how to handle this ?

Comment: Nice to hear that tips helped you :) In this situation the problem is more in json response structure and you have or to handle it as you do or you may do another nullable field for **Id** from response and insert it there, and make another Primary Key for your DB and EF. It's up to you now :)

Comment: The REST documentation I am using has some limitations like - I can query for a max of 10 ids and result will return max of 5 results per page (pageindex) ?
I am not able to understand that, when I query with 10 ids I get response with 5 results, how do I navigate to the next 5 items ?